# split-horizon with systemd-resolved

Tags: domain-name-system, systemd, resolve

I am on an Ubuntu box that uses `systemd-resolved` to resolve host names.

I would like to configure it, `systemd-resolved`, to use a DNS server, different than the main ones, just for some particular domain.

Is that possible? I am finding `systemd-resolved` man page pretty arduous in that regard.

**Update**: BTW, I know I can do that using a local `bind` or `dnsmasq` server, but I would prefer to stick to using just `systemd-resolved` if possible and not overcomplicate my setup.

**Update 2**: I have been told on the `systemd` IRC channel that this can not be done :-(

Comment: I was assuming it was with [SetDNS/SetLinkDNS](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved/) was created for this purpose. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I know, it's an old question, but if someone (like me) stumbles over this when searching for a solution: [this unix.stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442599/74722) was helpful to me (works when you want to use the link-DNS, but seems to be easy to change the DNS for the link and get the behaviour you want out of it.